# get the size of a file stored on my database

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to get the size of a PDF file already stored in my database

I try this

```
$sid = 1;
$getFile = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pwork WHERE id=?");
$getFile->bind_param('i', $sid);
if ($getFile->execute()) {
    $fileRes = $getFile->get_result();
    if ($f = $fileRes->fetch_object()) {
        $fileName = $f->work_file;
        $fileSize = filesize($fileName);
    }
}
```

and I got an error

```
( ! ) Warning: filesize(): stat failed for ch03-libre.pdf in xxx on line 57
```

my file is stored as `BLOB` and I need to get the file size like 5Mb

Comment: It's not finding the file. You probably need to put the directory prefix before the filename.

Comment: you mean I need to do something like this `$fileSize = filesize("mydir/".$fileName);`

Comment: Yes. But in you case I guess there is no path because its stored in the DB so you have to create the file first or you try the given answere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole file is inside the BLOB, you can use mysql functions to directly calculate how big the Blob is.

See this article:
https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/how-to-get-size-of-blob-in-mysql/

And this example:

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob_content) FROM test_blob WHERE id = 1
```

Length returned will be in bytes.